# Unable to get CMake Tutorial example to compile... Why?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to follow the official tutorial for `CMake` [for adding a version number and configured header file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/A%20Basic%20Starting%20Point.html#adding-a-version-number-and-configured-header-file). I have two directories:

- `Step1`
- `Step1_build`

`Step1` contains `CMakeLists.txt`, `TutorialConfig.h.in` and `tutorial.cxx`. Contents of each file follow:

## `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name
project(Tutorial VERSION 1.0)

# configure a header file to pass the version number to the source code
configure_file(TutorialConfig.h.in TutorialConfig.h)

# add directory to list of paths to search for include files
target_include_directories(Tutorial PUBLIC 
                           "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
                          )

# add the executable 
add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cxx)
```

## `TutorialConfig.h.in`

```
// the configured options and settings for Tutorial

#define Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR @Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR@
#define Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR @Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR@
```

## `tutorial.cxx`

```
#include "TutorialConfig.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cout << argv[0] << "Version" << Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR << "."
            << Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "argc=" << argc << std::endl;
    std::cout << "argv[1]=" << argv[1] << std::endl;
}
```

I then try to build using `cmake -S Step1 -B Step1_build`. But I get an error:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (target_include_directories)
> Cannot specify include directories for target "Tutorial" which is not built by this project

I've checked the instructions again and again, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Why won't the project compile?

Comment: Move line `add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cxx)` before `target_include_directories`

Comment: That worked. Wanna post that as a final answer?

Comment: hehe oki, quite strange that there is a mistake in the tutorial

Comment: A no, actually tutorial seems OK, they just don't post the complete file, so it might be confusing indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In CMake targets need to be defined before any modification of their properties (like include directories), so this line:

```
# add the executable 
add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cxx)
```

should be moved before the call to `target_include_directories`.